# Can we be careful with delete votes?

Tags: discussion

I notice questions getting delete votes that IMO should not be deleted. Current examples:

**UPDATE**:

[Should I ask for my job back after being terminated?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119297/should-i-ask-for-my-job-back-after-being-terminated) (2 votes)
<del>[Should I recommend a fired colleague?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119380/should-i-recommend-a-fired-colleague)</del> No longer the case
[Is it legal for company to use my work email to pretend I still work there?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/133270/is-it-legal-for-company-to-use-my-work-email-to-pretend-i-still-work-there)  (1 vote)
That last one is a blatant example of an incorrect delete vote

**END UPDATE**

These questions, though closed as off-topic, certainly do not meet the requirements for deletion:

- [Generally we only delete closed, low scoring posts with no answers or poor answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/delete-votes-and-you)
- [if the question has received upvoted answers, we will usually not delete the question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/when-flagging-to-delete-your-question-please-tell-us-the-reason)
- [a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

They have upvoted answers with serious content.
Please people, 'closed' is not the same as 'delete it'. [Let's be careful out there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pIkkzDagsY)

Note: I have even seen questions that have both delete and reopen votes at the same time.

Comment: "I have even seen questions that have both delete and reopen votes at the same time." - that's not unusual. Some of us think that too many questions are being closed too rapidly and vote to reopen.

Comment: Both of these seem to be advise on a specific choice and should not be reopened as they are currently IMO.  Should we be answer questions that boil down to "*What should I do*"?

Comment: @MisterPositive No they should not be reopened, but my point is they should not be deleted too.

Comment: Why not?  If they are garbage questions that benefit no one, why not clean them up if you notice them?

Comment: *"I have even seen questions that have both delete and reopen votes at the same time."* - Like the fired colleague one... 4 reopen and 2 delete... it should not be deleted IMO

Comment: This isn't the first time this topic has come up this year: [Let's try to work with users before chasing them off](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/lets-try-to-work-with-users-before-chasing-them-off)

Comment: The criteria for deletion (according to me) are (1) this seems unlikely to ever get reopened (with or without an edit) and (2) this isn't useful enough to make an exception. If you think there's still hope for the question getting reopened, fair enough, but if you think we should be making exceptions all over the place, I strongly disagree - keeping anything that's against our rules but is vaguely useful around is how you lose all quality standards.

Comment: Related: [Can something be done to prevent delete votes when a question has reopen votes or is being discussed on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166329)

Comment: @DavidK Although it's worth noting that's about deleting within *hours* and the examples here are a *week* old. It's reasonable to assume that regulars, or even OP, who might try to fix it might not see it within the first few hours, but that seems much less likely if we're talking about a week.

Comment: Good question, not something I'd noticed before