# (Done) This question should not be closed as 'unclear'

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[Misleading/out of date LinkedIn profiles - saying you still work for an employer when you don't](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67361/misleading-out-of-date-linkedin-profiles-saying-you-still-work-for-an-employer)

is closed as *Unclear what you're asking*. There is nothing unclear about it.
 It seems on-topic (there are [plenty of LinkedIn questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+linkedin) already - we even have a [linkedin](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) tag), my only objection is that it's a bit *What should I do?*
It also describes a quite common fact.

I came across the question because it had a *Delete* flag, which [I think is incorrect, because it has decent answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/can-we-be-careful-with-delete-votes).

I also suspect that the many downvotes are related to the attitude/judgment of the OP.

I want to suggest to:

- not delete<sup>*</sup>
- edit the opinion of the OP out of the question
- vote to reopen<sup>*</sup>
- upvote to 0<sup>*</sup>
- <del>add an (community wiki) answer containing the text from the *not malice/forgot* comments</del>

<sup>* I have already done these</sup>

Comment: I think the edit would be straightforward, just remove the final paragraph. It does seem like the question already has good answers, both from a personal perspective and per LinkedIn's policy. I voted to reopen.

Comment: It's been reopened - I removed the last paragraph as per @dwizum's suggestion. FWIW I think Jan is right it - got treated harshly because the OP came off poorly but the core question is not a bad one. I doubt the re-opening will make much difference to anything in the long run as it is such an old question. But tidy is as tidy does or something.

Comment: I didn't make the edit because I was mulling over whether or not it would throw things out of context in the question. I suppose the answers are still quite valid, but some of the comments don't make sense now, although that's probably OK given that comments are supposed to be transient anyways.

Comment: @dwizum With the question in its current form my 5th suggestion is no longer necessary. Edited that out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The question received enough votes and is open again.